# Conditionally render different arrays in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to conditionally map through two different arrays in a reusable component. I can't seem to get it to work. Obviously, I could just split them in two, but I'm trying to make the component reusable. Any ideas?

```
const fullStack = ["HTML", "CSS", "Javascript", "NodeJs", "React", "MongoDB", "Bootstrap"];
const  reactSkills=["React Query", "Redux", "Context API","Tailwind", "Custom Hooks","Supabase"];
```

```
               <div type={type}>
                    {type.map((skill)=> <li key={skill.id}>{skill}</li>)}  
                </div>
```

In a different component, I have the two different types attached to the reusable component.

```
            <EducationCard type="fullStack">
                <h1>Web Development Bootcamp - 2023</h1>
            </EducationCard>
            <EducationCard type="reactSkills">The Ultimate React Course</EducationCard>
```

I tried to conditionally render it like this:

```
{type === fullstack ? fullStack.map((skill)=> <li key={skill.id} >{skill}</li>) : reactSkills.map((skill)=> <li key={skill.id}>{skill}</li>)}
```

This didn't work (and is also not very good code), so any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does `skill.id` come from? Your arrays just contain plain strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put both of the arrays in an object and refer to them by the appropriate key

```jsx
const arrays = {
  fullStack: [
    /*...*/
  ],
  reactSkils: [
    /*...*/
  ],
};

const EducationCard = ({ type, children }) => (
  <>
    {children}
    {arrays[type] && (
      <ul>
        {arrays[type].map((skill, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{skill}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )}
  </>
);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much!